# JSONLD—Absolute URLs for @context

Tags: symfony4, json-ld, api-platform.com

I am using Symfony 4 and the [Api Platform](https://api-platform.com/), works fine so far. To implement stuff on the frontend, I am using [jsonld.js](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/jsonld.js/), which seams to be the »official« library to handle `ld+json` related actions, since it is directly linked at [json-ld.org](https://json-ld.org/).

However: `GET /api/v1` returns that:

```
{
  "@context": "/api/v1/contexts/Entrypoint",
  "@id":"/api/v1",
  "@type":"Entrypoint",
  "story":"/api/v1/stories",
  "author":"/api/v1/authors",
}
```

And trying to:

```
fetch('/api/v1')
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(json => jsonld.expand(json))
  .then(expanded => console.log(expanded))
```

results in:

> Error: Dereferencing a URL did not result in a valid JSON-LD object. Possible causes are an inaccessible URL perhaps due to a same-origin policy (ensure the server uses CORS if you are using client-side JavaScript), too many redirects, a non-JSON response, or more than one HTTP Link Header was provided for a remote context.

Changing `@context` value to: `http://localhost:8000/api/v1` and everything works, so the cause of the error are the relative urls.

Question:
Is it possible to set the »base url« either at the server or with jsonld.js? If so, what should be the preferred solution: Server- or clientside.

Answer (score 1):

Update: the ability to configure the URL generation strategy finally [landed in the master branch](https://github.com/api-platform/core/pull/3198), it will be available in the next minor release.

Unfortunately this isn't possible yet. The `ContextBuilderInterface` has been designed form the very beginning to be able to generate absolute URLs: https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/2ff3dd352facc0e0e5cf1af3e1cbc50277f6364f/src/JsonLd/ContextBuilder.php#L88

A Pull Request to make the generation style configurable has been opened but never finished: https://github.com/api-platform/core/pull/751

If a nice people want to take back this PR to finish it, it would be very appreciated!

Anyway it's a weird error. You should try to find the underlying issue (CORS headers not set correctly, wrong host configuration...).